# Reorder tabs in googlecustom

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I have some refinements set in my Google custom account, these refinements create a tabs in the search.

How do I re-order these tabs to a custom order?

I've tried re-ordering it in the `CSE context` file, but that didn't take effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible to reorder the tabs, Google creates its own tab order depending on what the user searched for. It seems that tabs will be ordered by the number of search results in each tab.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/An18flZxDWo

Answer (score 0):

this is possible, by ordering them in the CSE context file AND removing the setting top_refinements="x" completely